# My screen is not jumping to the next screen as required

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `RawMaterialButton` and I need to switch screen when the button is pressed, but it is not switching?

Here is my code - first Screen:

```
Widget _buildListItem(String picture) {
  return Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 130.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(picture),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0))),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          Container(
            height: 120.0,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Maple Mustard Tempeh',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                Text('Marinated kale, onion, tomato and roasted',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey
                  ),
                ),
                Text('garlic aioli on grilled spelt bread',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.0,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.grey
                    ),
                  ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),

                       Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('\u20B9 11.25',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 60.0,),
                          Cbutton(onPressed: ()=> item_details()),

                        ],
                      ),


              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],

      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

RawMaterialButton

```
return new RawMaterialButton(
  fillColor: Colors.green,
  splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 20.0,
        vertical: 8.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: const <Widget>[
         Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,),
         SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
         Text("Add", style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
        ),),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: onPressed,
  shape: StadiumBorder(),
);
```

}
}

Comment: What is `Cbutton`? Also what is `item_details()`? That's what clicking the button calls, so that's what needs to be looked into.

Comment: What's inside your onPressed method?

Comment: @Ovidiu Cbutton is separate dart file that contain   RawMaterialButton which  contain above code under RawMaterialButton.

Comment: You need to edit your question. Show Cbutton and item_details() code, those are the main subject of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change screens, you can user `Navigator`.

```
onPressed: () {  
      Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondScreen()
        ));
}
```

Comment: @ James Casia thanks but it shows error at Navigator.push(context it shows undefined field context